# TCP multithreaded server doesn't entirely work

Tags: java, network-programming

Well, to be honest it works just for one client, don't really know why. Also client is receiving everything two or three times. [ I've used telnet as a client. When I start another telnet session, it stays, but it doesn't give any output ]. 
I will add gui code if needed.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String s;
    initGUI();
    try {
        hostServer = new ServerSocket(port);
        socket = hostServer.accept();
        area.append(" "+socket+" connection\n");
        changeStatusTS(CONNECTED, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        cleanUp();
        changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        while(true) {
            multi ml = new multi(socket);
            ml.start();
        }
    }
}

static class multi extends Thread{

    public multi(Socket c) throws IOException {
        socket = c;
    }
    public void run(){
        String s;
        switch (connectionStatus) {
            case CONNECTED:
                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    if (toSend.length() != 0) {
                        out.print(toSend); out.flush();
                        toSend.setLength(0);
                        changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                    }
                    if (in.ready()) {
                        s = in.readLine();
                       if ((s != null) &&  (s.length() != 0)) {
                          if(s.equals("test")==true){
                          out.print("bazinga"); 
                          out.flush();
                      }

                     if (s.equals(END_CHAT_SESSION)) {
                        changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                     }
                     else {
                        appendToChatBox("INCOMING: " + s + "\n");
                        changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               cleanUp();
               changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
            }
            break;

         case DISCONNECTING:

            out.print(END_CHAT_SESSION); 
            out.flush();

            cleanUp();
            changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, true);
            break;

         default: break; 
         }
    }
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not looked at the entire code but an immediate problem looks to be that your server is not calling `accept()` in a loop.  I'd change your `main` to be something like the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String s;
    initGUI();
    hostServer = new ServerSocket(port);
    while (true) {
        try {
            // wait for the next client to connect
            socket = hostServer.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cleanUp();
            changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
            break;
        }
        area.append(" " + socket + " connection\n");
        // you probably don't want this or you want this to be per client?
        changeStatusTS(CONNECTED, true);
        // start a multi thread on the accepted socket
        Multi ml = new Multi(socket);
        ml.start();
    }
}
```

When a client calls connection, the server's `accept()` call returns and your code should create a new `Multi` thread to handle that connection.  Then the server should loop around and call `accept()` again, waiting for the next client to connect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank u Gray! Now it works better, but still I'm facing a problem, it establishes connection with new client, but the client can' write [ can't send to server ] and the messages from server reaches every next client, for example, I run a server, start telnet client [ connection ok ] and than type something in server. I'm starting next client and than getting message from server [ the message for the previous client ]. Hope u get my problem :(

Comment: I think you need a loop around the contents of your run method @iie.   Did you try and debug the code?  Put a break point at the start of `run()` and you will see that the client bails immediately.  You need to put some sort of loop so that each client waitings for IO and then performs some tasks.  I agree with @Kevin that you should try a simpler example of client/server if this is your first time.

Comment: well simple while true loop made the difference. It is almost perfect, thank u @Gray. I've made simpler client server, "even" the multithreded, but the combination of gui and multithreded server was kind of high wall for me. Well - it still is. Nevertheless thank u very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The two loops with a sleep() in makes no sense at all ...

```
while (true) {
     try {
 Thread.sleep(10);
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
     }

     while(true){

 multi ml = new multi(socket);
 ml.start();


       }
      }
   }
```

You should study some **simple** open source server-client code. This could be a good start:
http://www.cn-java.com/download/data/book/socket_chat.pdf

Another tip: do not start to mixup representation (Swing GUI) with processing threads. You will mess up everything. Try first to implement your server without any GUI.

Comment: damn, I thought I cut out those two while loops. I have a multithreded server without gui, what I need is to combine these two elements :/

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on your code, which seems to have some issues, you should look at the very simple socket server example in the javadocs for Executor service at:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html